# What is the right way to manage namespaces in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

Most of my programming background is in C++ and Java, but for professional reasons I'm starting to learn Python.  One of the first things that I noticed was Python's new approach to packages and namespaces, but after googling around for awhile and doing some experimenting I thought I started to get the hang of it.

Then I read [this](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html), which indicated that everything I had just learned was wrong.  So now I'm confused again, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I should organize my code.

---

Here's a very concrete question which I don't really know how to answer correctly for any version of Python, and in particular I don't know if the answer changed from Python 2 to 3.  Let's say I want a class in a cloned github repo, stored in:

```
/Users/me/my_teams_code/some_project/package/IWantThisClass.py
```

But let's say I have some other projects here:

```
/Users/me/my_own_code/some_other_project1/...
/Users/me/my_own_code/some_other_project2/...
/Users/me/my_own_code/some_other_project3/...
```

each of which use IWantThisClass.  One strategy seems to be to just manually add the correct directory to sys.path every time, but this is rather cumbersome - especially when I'm just experimenting in a Jupyter notebook.  The solution that I settled upon after googling around is to add the package directory to my PYTHONPATH variable in bash; this works in the sense that "import IWantThisClass" works just fine.  But I read in Coghlan's post above:

> "This next trap exists in all current versions of Python, including 3.3, and can be summed up in the following general guideline: 'Never add a package directory, or any directory inside a package, directly to the Python path'."

So what is the "correct" way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what "package directory" you added?  What that warning means is that if `package` is the directory containing the top-level `__init__.py` of the package, you should add its *containing* directory to the path.  It's not clear if that's what you mean by "package directory".  It's difficult to know which directories you should be adding to the path without knowing which of the directories in your examples have `__init__.py` and thus are Python packages.

Comment: Well, one comment is that Python 3 no longer requires __init__.py for imports (one of many things I learned from the link...) and indeed when I add /Users/me/my_teams_code/some_package/package to PYTHONPATH the imports work with or without __init__.py.  But let's assume for the sake of argument that the directory "package" contains the top level __init__.py file.

Comment: Another comment: I may be involved in the process of updating our code to be Python 3 compliant, so for the sake of this question let's treat the contents of my_teams_code as something that I have control over.

Comment: As described in [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification), `__init__.py` is optional only for namespace packages.  Most packages will still want an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if `package` is the top-level directory of your package, you should add the directory *containing* `package` to `sys.path`.  If what you want to import is not a package but a single module (i.e., just an individual `.py` file not in a package directory), then that module should be in a directory on `sys.path`/

Exactly how you should add these paths is another question.  For situations where I want to add one-off things to the path, I find that the easiest thing to do is to create a `.PTH` file inside a "site directory" --- either the main site-packages directory or the user-specific site-packages directory.  In that `.PTH` file you can list other directories which will then be added to `site.path`.  So you can have your own little `my_stuff.pth` file that sets up `sys.path` with directories you need.  This avoids having to add boilerplate code to each script to manually modify `sys.path`.  You can read about how to do this in the documentation for the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

Another, perhaps better answer is that you should try to avoid adding specific directories to `sys.path` in order to access specific files.  Rather, you should try to *install* the relevant packages, which will let Python set up the paths for you.  If you're using in-development packages that you don't want to clutter your main site-packages will, you can use [`python setup.py develop`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode) or [`pip install --editable`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs) to install the packages "in-place".  (That is, the package files will stay where they are, not be moved into the global Python site-packages, and the installer will update the appropriate `.PTH` files so that the newly-installed package is importable.)

In short, ultimately you need to move away from viewing it in terms of "this file wants this class from this other file".  The unit that you should be concerned with is the installable package or module.  If you're writing code that wants SomeClass, you should install the package/module that provides SomeClass and then import it; don't try to manipulate `sys.path` on an ad-hoc basis to target the individual file/class that you want without installing its package.  (As mentioned, `setup.py develop` and `pip install --editable` allow you to do this while still keeping the actual files where you want.)

Comment: Both of these solutions worked - thanks!  The first solution - manually creating .pth files - felt like a bit of a hack, so I decided to invest a little time learning  how to create installable packages.  This was shockingly difficult to piece together from Python documentation and Google searches given that it took about ten lines of code in the end, but it's already paying off as the package works just like any other package in my virtual environments.